# Redirection to wrong language since 3.4.3

Tags: joomla-3.4, language

When I click a link in an article to another article with no explicit lang in the query string, then a redirect occurs to a url with the language set in the query string. This language is not, however, necessarily the language set in the language switcher.

This behaviour is new - since upgrading from 3.3.6 to 3.4.3.

Does anyone have any idea, why the language switcher setting would be ignored, and where the language which is used might come from (the browser?), and/or where the redirect occurs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I have found a fix for the problem, by adding 
$lang_code = $this->getLanguageCookie();
to line 348 in the plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php file.
It appears that the cookie should be used, but in this case (SEF not used) isnt'. I'll keep researching. Maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a bug and has been fixed here:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/7427
The fix will be available in Joomla 3.4.4
If you need a quick fix now, see my comment above.

Comment: +1 Nice find. I've asked when J3.4.4 will be released and will post here when I get a response

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I reverted to the plugin that I had in 3.3.6 and it is working, let's see if 3.4.4 solves this...